# Make a CSV file or table into an ImageCollection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, function

I have a CSV file that has 30 years of annual data that relates to my ROI. For the analysis I am doing, I want to turn this CSV file into an ImageCollection with each image being a single year having the the constant value from that year in each pixel of my roi. I could make a single image as follows:

```
var image = ee.Image.constant(5.5)//or whatever value
  .clip(geometry)
  .addBands(ee.Image.constant(2018).rename('year'))
  
Map.addLayer(image)
```

I could manually make each image and create an ImageCollection from them but I would like to automate the process or write a function so I can do this for various climate data files. Is there a way to do this? I currently use the JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make it into a function to apply to each feature in your table (FeatureCollection). The function should return an `ee.Image`, and when you map it to your table, make it into an `ee.ImageCollection`:

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection(
  table.map(function(feature){
    return ee.Image(
      ee.Number(
        feature.get("value")
        )
    ).rename("value")   
    .addBands(ee.Image(ee.Number(feature.get("year"))).rename("year")) // year as a band.
    .set({year:feature.get("year")})  // year as a property 
    .clip(geometry)
  })
)
```

I also added the option to set the "year" as a property, which might be useful instead of having it as an additional band.

Example using 10 random values from 2011 to 2020 (10 years):

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8f2fcfe18e1825ffbed9e2bdf3465a0e

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. The only change I needed to make for my specific table was to explicitly cast the value and year bands, i.e. `.cast({'value': ee.PixelType('float', -31, 31)})`